# Resize JPanel from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I want to create a little game in Java using Netbeans. For now I have a JFrame and two JPanels.
The JFrame contains both JPanels and a button. My intent is to click on this button and resize one of the JPanels (from 0 to >0 width).
Till now I menaged to resize the frame but I can't figure out how to resize the JPanel.
This is what I've done so far:

```
Structure
   frame
    |_ panel 1
    |_ panel 2
    |_ button

 __________________
|  _        _      |
| | |      | |    _|
| | |      | |   | |
| | |      | |   |>|  
| | |      | |   |_|
| |_|      |_|     |
|__________________|

on click should expand frame and panel
 ______________________
|  _        _____      |
| | |      |     |    _|
| | |      |     |   | |
| | |      |     |   |>|  ->
| | |      |     |   |_|
| |_|      |_____|     |
|______________________|
```

This is the JPanel to resize

```
public class ToResize extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    ...

    public void resize(int width) {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth() + width, this.getHeight()));
    }
}
```

This is the JFrame with the button

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ...

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (panelToResize.getWidth() == 0) {
            panelToResize.resize(100);
        } else {
            panelToResize.resize(-100);
        }
        validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) if you'll resize JFrame too, then you have to call

a/ `setPrefferedSize(getPrefferedSize()+-)` for `JFrame.pack();`

b/ `setPrefferedSize(getPrefferedSize()+-)` for `panelToResize` and then call `JFrame.pack();`

2/ if you only change size betweens `JPanels` and `JFrame` size stays remained, then you have to call `revalidate()` plus `repaint()` to the `panelToResize`,

3/ but everything depends of used [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

> My intent is to click on this button and resize one of the JPanels (from 0 to >0 width).

Use a `CardLayout`, or a `JSplitPane`, or call `panel.setVisible(boolean)`.

Comment: finally looks like as `Dockable Panel` +1

Answer (score 0):

Change `setSize()` to `setPreferredSize()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do that same thing in a different way.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    panelToResize.setVisible(!panelToResize.isVisible());
    if(panelToResize.isVisible()) {
        jButton1.setText("<<");
    } else {
        jButton1.setText(">>");
    }
}
```

Why?

1 - Hidden panel still work just like a visible one.

2 - Need to know rather the panel is extended or not? `panelToResize.isVisible();`

3 - The layout on your JFrame still works as intended.

Answer (score -2):

You can just use:

```
mainPanel.setResizeHorizontal(true);
mainPanel.setResizeVertical(true)
```

and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Please clean up this answer; good grammar and English is useful, along with using the provided formatting tools - but in particular you should cite why this fixes the problem.